# Remove sprite from stage in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have this code for a message to appear on stage when player finishes drag and drop. I would like this sprite to be removed when a button is clicked for the next frame. Can someone help me with the code?

```
 stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, EntFrame);
 function EntFrame (e:Event):void 
  {
     if (CntP1+CntP2+CntP3+CntP4+CntP5+CntP6+CntP7+CntP8 == 40)
{
    var w:int = 400, h:int = 200;
    var win:Sprite = new Sprite();
    win.name = "Mywin";
    addChild(win);


 // draw rounded rect with subtle vertical linear gradient fill and blue stroke
    win.graphics.lineStyle(4,0x0077ff);
    var mat:Matrix = new Matrix();
    mat.createGradientBox(w, h, 90 * (Math.PI / 180));
    win.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR,[0xffffff,0xeeeeee],[1.00,1.00],[0,255],mat);
    win.graphics.drawRoundRect(0,0,w,h,15,15);

    // show center "YOU WIN!" text
    var tf:TextField = new TextField();
    tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    tf.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
    tf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial, Verdana",36,0x454545,true);
    tf.text = "Κέρδισες!";
    tf.selectable = false;
    win.addChild(tf);
    tf.x = w/2 - tf.width/2;
    tf.y = h/2 - tf.height/2;

    // add a drop shadow
    var dropShadow:DropShadowFilter = new DropShadowFilter(3,45,0,.35,8,8,1,3);
    win.filters = [dropShadow];

    // center the graphic
    win.x = stage.stageWidth/2 - win.width/2;
    win.y = stage.stageHeight/2 - win.height/2;


}
```

}

Comment: You're probably going to have a whole stack of them to remove, since you're adding a new one on every frame. The problem is that you're not keeping a reference to any of them, so it's kind of tough to get hold of them to call removeChild(). Honestly, the whole function needs a rewrite, but there's not enough information in your question to allow for suggestions for the best way to rewrite it to meet whatever the overall goal is.

Comment: I have 8 movie clips on stage. The player click them and they became invisible and 8 new movie clips in a different position became visible. Thats it. When this process is finished i want the text message to appear and when player move to the next game in a different frame i want this message to disappear. I am new to flash and i am self taught and i have many difficulties. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't written well and needs rewriting to ensure reuse or scalability of your project, but here's a quick way out.

make a holder Sprite, something like

```
var messageHolder:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(messageHolder);
```

add all the messages to that holder in any fashion you like. When you need to erase the contents of that holder, call following method:

```
function clearHolderContents(holder:DisplayObjectContainer):void
{
   if (holder.numChildren < 1)
   return; // no need to continue this method if the target is empty

   for (var i:int = holder.numChildren - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      removeChild(holder.getChildAt(i));
}
```

This method can clear contents of any DisplayObjectContainer => use it for your messageHolder:

```
clearHolderContents(messageHolder);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am so sorry but i need some more information to understand what you mean. where shall i write this code? after if?

Comment: Add a holder sprite somewhere in the beginning - before you create the message. Then add the message stuff to the holder (e.g. instead of addChild() use messageHolder.addChild() ). Copy-paste the function clearHolderContents() somewhere in the very beginning and then call it wherever you want to any holder (e.g. messageHolder).

Comment: I think i did whatever you said but now i have this error:Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 165 1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 1.  I will post my code to tell me where i am wrong. Thank yoy for helping me.

Comment: The error states that you've called some method with incorrect number of arguments. It's some function that expects 1 argument. I can only guess that it's either clearContentHolder(HolderName) or addChild(ChildName).